# GitHub Archive Google Big Query repositories language information for 2015

Tags: api, github, google-bigquery

I have a problem with retrieving language information from GitHub Archive Google BigQuery since the structure of the tables changed which was at the beginning of 2015.

When querying github_timeline table I have a field named repository_language. It allows me to get my language statistics.
Unfortunately for 2015 the structure has changed and the table doesn't contain any events after 2014.
For example the following query doesn't return any data:

```
select
repository_language, repository_url, created_at
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
where
PARSE_UTC_USEC(created_at) > PARSE_UTC_USEC('2015-01-02 00:00:00')
```

Events for 2015 are in: githubarchive:month & githubarchive:day tables. None of them have language information tho (or at least repository_language column).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Look at payload field
It is string that, I think,  actually holds JSON with all "missing" attributes

You can process this using [JSON Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions)

[image]

> Added Query

Try as below:

```
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.head.repo.language') AS language,
  COUNT(1) AS usage
FROM [githubarchive:month.201601] 
GROUP BY language
HAVING NOT language IS NULL
ORDER BY usage DESC
```

Comment: check query I added to my answer

Comment: But this query looks into pull request events, not push events. Not every repository has pull requests.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Excellent explanation, thank you! Also, what tool are you using to view the structure of the gitarchive data (as in your screenshot)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I should start a new question for this, but it seems that one of the primary issues this asker and myself faced/are facing is how to do we the structure and possibilities of the payload field? I.e., how do we understand the structure of the JSON within the payload field? Given the answer I see that "$.pull_request" is a valid top level key, but what other options are there?

Answer (score 1):

What Mikhail said + you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.language') language, COUNT(*) c
FROM [githubarchive:month.201501]
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: I thought of this, but not every repository has pull requests, so I'm losing a lot of info...

Comment: I have the same question @BasiaF did: how do we see all the other top-level options? Understanding what can possibly be in the payload field is the challenge--and I can't find any documentation which casts any light on how to go about grappling with the contents of the payload field. Understanding the various Github event types is just the beginning, but doesn't really help one understand what's in the payload field.